# SSL certificate and public keys

Tags: ssl

Could someone explain to me the following:

**Who creates the public key during CSR**? Is it CA's responsibility to offer it or it depends on the certificate requester? If the latter is true, in which way the browser client may include in its truststore this public key as  to verify the SSL certificate sent from server? If the former is true, how many public keys a CA owns and in which way are all these keys known to the browser client? This is a point I cannot find or give a satisfactory answer since I cannot imagine the client holds a database of an enormous number of public keys...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Public and private key can only be generated as a pair. Since the CA should not know the private key, the requester has to generate that pair himself.
2. While the browser has to store the public key of every trustworthy CA, it does not have to include the public key of every https-enabled website like `prettykittens.org` in its truststore.

So how does the client judge the authenticity of the site?

During the SSL-handshake, the webserver sends its public key and a message signed using CA's public key that roughly says "This is Company XY's public key for prettykittens.org" (aka a certificate). Then the browser only has to verfiy the signature using the CA's public key and is good to go.

Comment: From what you say, I deduce that the client does not care about the public key inside the certification. So, it verifies the signature using the public key found inside its truststore and not this found inside certification, isn't it?

Comment: Yes and no - the client needs the server's public key during the SSL-handshake to encrypt the messages during negotiation of the session key.